# Change font color of div on click of button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, colors

I want to change the font color of my div on the click of a button using javascript. I have two buttons, 'Green" and 'Red'.

```
<button type="button" class="green">Green</button>
<button type="button" class="red">Red</button>
```

This is my div

```
<div id="timer"></div>
```

currently the font is red (default color), but once 'green' is clicked it will go green and when 'red' is clicked it will go back to red.

I know this is probably very simply but for some reason I can't get it to work :)

If you know how would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's the simplest solution to change color without Jquery : **http://jsfiddle.net/8jay6r3n/**

Just add `onclick` event to button like this : `onclick="document.getElementById('timer').style.color = 'red'"`

Some documentation about it exist here : **http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp**

---

If you want to use jQuery, than here example **http://jsfiddle.net/8jay6r3n/2/** 
You can use `inline style` or add `class` to change color of text.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting started with this stuff, you will have a much easier time if you use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library.

Simply add the following code inside the `<head>` of your document to install jQuery and give you access to the `$` function:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now your solution should be something like:

```
$('#green').click( function() { $('#timer').css('color','green'); } );
$('#red').click( function() { $('#timer').css('color','red'); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using jQuery

```
$('.green').click( function() { $('#timer').css('color','green'); } );
$('.red').click( function() { $('#timer').css('color','red'); } );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8dhzK/55/

Answer (score 0):

This is a example with links :

the Javascript :

```
<script language="javascript">
function changecolor(color) {

document.getElementById('timer').style.color=color;

}

</script>
```

Your links :

```
<a href="javascript:changecolor('#000000');">Black</a> 
<a href="javascript:changecolor('#FF0000');">Red</a>
```

Your div :

```
<div id="timer" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:10px">Timer</div>
```

For buttons, its probably the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery then it will be lot easier to implement. You can the function in either js file or `<script>` tag.

```
   $('#timer').css('color','green'); 
});
$('#red').click( function() {
   $('#timer').css('color','red'); 
});
```

And if you want to use pure javascript, use either "addEventListener" or 'click' for the click event and then add styling in each tag/element you want to apply css on.